A surjective group homomorphism from $\mathrm{Sp}(2n)$ to $\mathrm{U}(n)$?
Is there a Lie group homomorphism from $\mathrm{Sp}_\mathbb{R}(2n)$ to $\mathrm{U}_\mathbb{C}(n)$ whose restriction to $\mathrm{U}_\mathbb{C}(n)$ is an identity?
I apologize for the brief question, but this covers everything I wanted to ask.
There is a homotopy equivalence $\Psi \mapsto \Psi(\Psi^t \Psi)^{-1/2}$ but does this give a Lie group homomorphism?
If there is a duplicate answer, then please give me the link. If there is a reason why such homomorphism doesn't exist, then that also would be appreciated.

I'm not sure why this question receives all the close votes, it seems fine to me.
I think we should look at the more general question: for what groups $G, H$ with $H \subset G$ can we have a morphism $G \to H$ that acts on the identity on $H$?
The first thing you should realize is that the kernel of any morphism is a normal subgroup. I will call it $N$ for normal, but please do not confuse this with the standard terminology $N$ for the subgroup of upper triangular matrices.
Now as a set  (or topological space) we must have $G = H \times N$. But the group structure must also play a role. What we get is that $G$ is a semi-direct product of $H$ and $N$.
To see that this doesn't apply for the specific groups you are asking about, we just notice that the Lie algebra of $G$ is simple and hence $G$ doesn't have any connected non-trivial normal subgroups.
Approaching it from the other side and saying: "Can we make a topological product '$G = H \times $ something' where the something still has a somewhat natural relation to the Lie group structure?", I suggest you look into the Cartan decomposition.
